# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined -Angular ,Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here I add my service file code.I want to store data in firebase but I can't get data.I got my data in console but get some error & not push in firebase

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Contact } from './logic/contact';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
list: AngularFireList<any>;
createcontact:Contact = new Contact();
  constructor(private firebase:AngularFireDatabase) { } 
  insertdata(contact: Contact) {
// here I get my data in console
        console.log(contact);
        this.list.push({
          name: contact.name,
          email:contact.email,
          phoneno:contact.phoneno,
          notes:contact.notes,
          address:contact.address,
          relation:contact.relation 
        });
      }
  updatedata(contact: Contact) {
    this.list.update(contact._id,{
      name: contact.name,
      email: contact.email,
      phoneno: contact.phoneno,
      notes: contact.notes,
      address: contact.address,
      relation: contact.relation
    });
  }
  }
```

the error is like

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you push data to `firebase`. Try the following:

```
    export class DataService {
    list: AngularFireList<any>;
    createcontact:Contact = new Contact();
      constructor(private firebase:AngularFireDatabase) { } 
      insertdata(contact: Contact) {
    // here I get my data in console
            console.log(contact);
            this.list = this.firebase.list('/lists');
            if (contact) {
             this.list.push({
              name: contact.name,
              email:contact.email,
              phoneno:contact.phoneno,
              notes:contact.notes,
              address:contact.address,
              relation:contact.relation 
            });
          }
        }



updatedata(contact: Contact) {
    if ( contact) {
            this.list.set(contact._id,{
              name: contact.name,
              email: contact.email,
              phoneno: contact.phoneno,
              notes: contact.notes,
              address: contact.address,
              relation: contact.relation
            });
          }
    }
 }
```

Comment: [ts]
Type 'ThenableReference' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<any>'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type 'ThenableReference'.

Comment: @PoojaPatel my bad I made a typo mistake check the edit

Comment: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'list.name'

Comment: That means your object contact is empty, so check its value

Comment: For anyone like me trying to work out the working difference between the question and answer code, @Melchia is defining which list in Firebase to add it to with this line: `this.list = this.firebase.list('/lists');`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else encounter this kind of problem, I solved my issue by doing the following:

Define your variable as:

```
list$: AngularFireList<any[]>;
```

Then, in the constructor you initialize it as:

```
this.list$ = firebase.list('/contact'); //your path api
```

after that, push can be as follows:

```
this.list$.push([whatever]);
```

Hope it helps.